# Integral of chain rule of total derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

I am trying to understand how you would 'reverse' the chain rule for a derivative.

If I have a function $$f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$$ then differentiating w.r.t $r$ gives: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$

Is there a formal way of reversing this rather than 'by inspection'? I thought integrating w.r.t $r$ would be the way but I expect I must be making an error in my integration:

$$\partial f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\partial x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\partial y$$

Now would the $\partial x$s and the $\partial y$s 'cancel'? Wouldn't that leave me with $\partial f= 2\partial f$?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: you CANNOT multiply by partials $\partial x, \partial y\ldots$ You can only multiply by total differentials $dx, dy\ldots$ Actually, both operations make no sense mathematically, but the latter tends to yield correct results, because it can be interpreted in terms of theorems of differential calculus. (Or in terms of infinitesimals, like physicists do).

Comment: Said in another way, $x$ is a 2 variable function. For 1 variable functions, you can write $\frac{df}{dx}dx = df$. For 2 variable functions $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr = dx_r$, emphasis on the subscript $r$. $dx = dx_r + dx_{\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, and a $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Many books write out the chain rule like this. Technically, it's incorrect. When you take $f: (u,v) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, the outside function, and form the composition $f \circ g$ where $g: (r,\theta) \mapsto (u,v)$, this composition is a new function and should be given a new name like $z = f\circ g: (r,\theta) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Notice how I'm using $(u,v)$ and not $(x,y)$. You already used $x$ and $y$ as function names. I shouldn't write $x = x(r,\theta)$ and $y = y(r,\theta)$ as is done frequently (I actually do this a lot). Instead, I labeled the outputs $u = x(r, \theta)$ and $v = y(r,\theta)$.

The chain rule should always be stated: "derivative of the composition = ( derivative of the outside function )( derivative of the inside function )." As stated, you have the derivative of the outside function on the left? Making me confused on how you are defining $f$. It makes it seem like $f$ is a 3 input function. With this notation, the chain rule should be written

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}  $$

It looks weird, mainly because I'm objecting to writing $x = x(r,\theta)$. Because, technically since you used $x$ as a function name, $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ doesn't make sense. This would be like, in single variable calculus, writing $\frac{d}{df}$ when $f$ is the function name. However given a single variable function $f$, producing outputs of $f(x)$, $\frac{d}{d(\;f(x)\;)}$ does make sense (this would be a derivative in the range of the function - or the domain of the inverse function - i.e. $\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}$ where $y = f(x)$)

To undo the chain rule:

$$\int \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\;dr = z(r,\theta) + F(\theta)  $$

If you wanted to see this, in the way that you are doing, you'd have to do a u-substitution. If I give you

$$\int \frac{d}{d(g(x))}f(g(x)) \frac{dg}{dx}dx $$

You let $u = g(x)$ and proceed to find $ \int f'(u) du = f(u) = f(g(x))$. You'd do the same thing here. Actually nevermind, you will need multivariable calculus and just go in reverse (the following is a repeat of what I've already written down above)

$$ \int \nabla f(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta)) \cdot \Big<\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\Big>dr \\
= \int \frac{\partial }{\partial r}f(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta)) dr \\
= f(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta)) + F(\theta)
$$

Comment: Thank you! This was a lot but I think I understand most of it. Could you clarify how you went from the first to the second line of the final integral? Does the first line become $\int\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x(r,\theta),(y(r,\theta))\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr + \int\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr$ ?

Comment: Would you also know of any literature where I could learn recap these basic calculus concepts? I have studied real analysis so I'm not a complete beginner, but I feel like things you have had to explain in your answer were never taught as they were taken for granted, so I still make mistakes with things like notation and am not entirely sure of the rigour of sometimes treating derivatives like fractions, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @cluelessatthis Yeah no problem! The integrand in the first line is precisely the right hand side of my first equation. It's $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$. So I can set this right hand side equal to the left hand side to make it $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$. However, $z$ is what I defined to be the composite function $z := f(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta))$. So $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}f(x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta))$. Let me know if you have more questions too

Comment: @cluelessatthis Notation has become a big thing for me lately. I wish someone taught me this earlier, because it makes math so much easier. I've never taken real analysis. The only resource I can give is my calc 1-3 textbook:  Calculus single variable by Jon Rogawski and Calculus multivariable by Jon Rogawski. Both second editions. I seem to never understand the material in a course while taking it. But 2 years later, things seem to click - pulling everything together from different courses(maybe it's like going to the gym. You don't see results until you break down muscles and heal over time)

Comment: @cluelessatthis What helped me a lot was function notation and function composition. Then generalizing both concepts to multivarialbe functions (wikipedia is a good source- and actually if you read the wikipedia page on function notation, me defining $f$ as $f: (u,v) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is not standard. The symbol $\mapsto$ always has a point on the left hand side and a point on the right hand side. So something like $(u,v) \mapsto (u^2 + v + u)$ would be better. While in my post I had the point (u,v) being mapped to a set $\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't make sense - I hoped to get across that

Comment: the image of $(u,v)$ was an element in $\mathbb{R}$. So $(u,v) \mapsto t\in \mathbb{R}$ would be better

Comment: @cluelessatthis For the fraction thing and derivatives, you might try reading this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Definition). $d$ is another operator, like $d/dx$, like $\int$,  like $2+$ is an "operator" which would turn 7 into 9, -3 into -1, etc.  I'm still grappling with this too, so this may be wrong, but if you want to view $\frac{d}{dx}f$ (notice how I put $f$ off to the side, so you see $\frac{d}{dx}$ as one full symbol) as $\frac{df}{dx}$, then the two are equivalent if $df$ is defined as in the wikipedia article ($\Delta x = dx$)